# Mixing KOMAscript and geometry

Tags: koma-script, geometry

I have a document that uses the KOMAscript srcrprt document class. For some pages I need to setup custom margins using absolute values. I tried to use the geometry package for that, as follows:

```
\newgeometry{..options..}

..custom page..

\restoregeometry
```

However this does not work as expected. As soon as I add `\usepackage{geometry}` to the preamble, the KOMAscript document layout is thrashed.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: You can try `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `geometry` package has a very useful option, namely `pass`.

If you call

```
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

the package will not set any pagination parameter, but just load itself and make the `\newgeometry` command available.

An example of usage is in the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
   % ’pass’ disregards the package layout,
   %  so the original ’book’ layout is memorized here.
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}% changes the first page dimensions.
   Page 1
\restoregeometry % restores the original ’book’ layout.
   Page 2 and more
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

For several release KOMA-Script provides an undocumented option `usegeometry` to interact with package `geometry`. Since KOMA-Script 3.22 this is an documented option (of package `typearea`). It translates the page settings of package `typearea` into page settings of package `geometry` and passes them, e.g., as options to `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[usegeometry]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}% changes the first page dimensions.
   Page 1
\restoregeometry % restores the original typearea layout.
   Page 2 and more
\end{document}
```

The cooperation makes it even possible to change page size or page orientation using `typearea` and then change the margins using `geometry`, something current `geometry` does not provide using `\newgeometry`. But in this case you should use `typearea`'s commands to store and restore the geometries.

Comment: Good to know! although the possibility to use the `pass` option in the geometry package already did the trick for me.

Comment: @Grodriguez: Understand and that's OK. I wanted only to show another perspective.